# How to scale a QGraphicsEllipseItem with the Zoom Level of QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I have a QGraphicsView on a widget which im adding a number of items to.

some of these are polygons and some are ellipses (Both QGraphicsItems) when i zoom the Graphics view

```
void Test::on_verticalSlider_sliderMoved(int position)
{
    ui->graphicsView->scale(1.1,1.1);
}
```

the ellipses just get bigger and bigger but i want them to shrink so that they basically stay the same shape no matter how far zoomed in i am, so basically i want the polygons to be zoomed in on but not the points i have plotted onto these polygons...if that makes sense

dont know it makes it easier but all of the ellipse points plotted at any one time are within the same QGraphicsItemGroup so there could be a flag i can set on the entire group to do this?

anyway i would be greatful for any help with this

thanks

EDIT ------ CODE SAMPLE

item is the QGraphicsEllipseItem, and m_group_point is a QGraphicsItemGroup

```
 item->setParentItem(m_group_point.get());
```

then i add the group to a scene

```
m_scene2->addItem(m_group_point.get());
```

then add that scene to the view

```
ui->graphicsView->setScene(m_scene2.get());
```

they are `.get` because they are shared pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, ignoreTransformation indeed a proper way to go.

> **QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations**: The item ignores inherited transformations (i.e., its position is still anchored to its parent, but the parent or view rotation, zoom or shear transformations are ignored). This flag is useful for keeping text label items horizontal and unscaled, so they will still be readable if the view is transformed. When set, the item's view geometry and scene geometry will be maintained separately. You must call deviceTransform() to map coordinates and detect collisions in the view. By default, this flag is disabled. This flag was introduced in Qt 4.3.

About stay in the middle, you should move ellipses within *scene* to proper position, so they have proper scene coordinates, and then you instruct to ignore transformation of the view, so they will ignore any zooming/rotation/etc as mentioned in documentation.

Comment: Ok i add each item to a group and then add the group to a scene as an item and then add the scene to the view to display it. so what do you mean `move the ellipses within scene to proper position`??

Comment: can you pls copy-paste a bit of code where you actually create ellipses and them to the group. can be a pseudo code for simplicity

Comment: but then you actually create ellipses how you specify their position? I mean QGraphicsEllipseItem

Comment: `item->setRect(x,y,0.3,0.3);` setting the x y position and then the width and height of the ellipse

Comment: 0.3, 0.3 that doesnt look right.. because you plan to _ignore transformations_ so size of an object should be at least more then a pixel =) may be you have same thing with x,y... like 0.6, 0.7 .. that's why they are in a center (0,0)

Comment: No i want them to be small dots and then plot correctly until the flag is set then they go smaller and into the middle of the screen

Comment: again.. items which are ignore transformation drawn using coordinates they have.. can you add into logs something like: qDebug() << youEllipse->pos() or boundingRect() and post in here..

Comment: this is an example of one of the ellipses `boundingRect()` `QRectF(20.9,40.2833 1.3x1.3) `

Comment: well if item->pos() gives you (0,0), that's exactly why it's in the centre.. try item->move(0,0) to see if it makes any difference

Comment: But its only in the centre after the flag is set before then all the points are where there meant to be .. and how do you mean `item->move(0,0)` what will that do except move them all to 0,0 ?

Comment: sorry, I obviously mean (20,20) or something whatever != 0.. long day.. debugging some crappy code..

Comment: so when the flag is set now it moved all the points to the coordinate, out of interest the points are in the correct place still relative to each other just the entire group had got small at placed itself at 0,0

Comment: so now time to move a group =) and it's small obviously because items inside the group are small

Answer (score 2):

The Qt docs states this about the flag QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations: -

> The item ignores **inherited** transformations (i.e., its position is
>   still anchored to its parent, but the parent or view rotation, zoom or
>   shear transformations are ignored).

Which is what you want. You've added your items to a QGraphcisItemGroup. For this, Qt help states: -

> QGraphicsItemGroup ignores the ItemIgnoresTransformations flag on its
>   children (i.e., with respect to the geometry of the group item, the
>   children are treated as if they were transformable).

Reading into this, the QGraphicsItem uses the ItemIgnoreTransformations flag based on its parent, which in your case is the QGraphicsGroup, but this class ignores the flag on its children, which is likely to be causing the issue you're seeing.

Therefore, do not set the flag on the parent group, but on its children.

Comment: Thanks, turns out that i needed to set the flags per item not for the entire group, now iv done that its working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the ItemIgnoresTransformations flag on the objects that you want to keep constant-sized.

Comment: Yea i have tried that if i do that then they dont plot in the correct place to begin with they just all clump in the middle instead of plotting where their supposed to be, but they do keep their size on zoom, but wouldnt call this solved yet